# Protecting yourself with latex gloves

Tags: safety, protection, shock

Would wearing white latex gloves(doctor gloves) protects you from getting shocked when repairing electronics?
And is there a reason why you seldom see anyone wearing gloves when dealing with electronics?

Comment: I see Louis wearing nitril gloves all the time, but obviously for other reasons. Unless the gloves are specifically designed to protect against electric shocks, why would you put your life in the hands of them?

Comment: Not an answer, but: don't assume medical gloves are latex; they can just as easy be [nitrile, PVC, or neoprene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medical_glove).

Comment: @PlasmaHH Louis Rossman (the [youtuber](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCl2mFZoRqjw_ELax4Yisf6w)) wears gloves because he works on customer machines. Some customer machines are incredibly [dirty](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nD9E8p6J95w). Besides Louis uses solder and flux daily, which is not healthy for humans on the long term.

Comment: @Jeroen3: I think I said, obviously for other reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Latex gloves are very easily punctured with a loose strand of copper.

To work with live conductors you need thick rubber gloves. Electrician Gloves.
And proper training in how to check and use them.

[image]
([image source](https://www.knipex.com/index.php?id=1216&L=1&page=art_detail&parentID=1324&groupID=1545&artID=4301))

Comment: That are regularly (before each use) inspected using a proper procedure, stored properly and thrown away after their expiry date.

Comment: @Jeroen3, I think that this answer only address the first question (_Would wearing white latex gloves(doctor gloves) protects you from getting shocked when repairing electronics?_). The second question (_And is there a reason why you seldom see anyone wearing gloves when dealing with electronics?_) was not answered.

Comment: @mguima They do not protect you from electrical shocks. They only protect you or the electronics from chemicals or contamination.

Comment: @Jeroen3, I think the other reasons why you _seldom see anyone wearing gloves when dealing with electronics_ are: most of times you don't repair the equipment while it is working/ installed (you work on them in a lab or a shop or something just like); even if you need to turn it on to make a measure, you do it in a controlled way, you try do not touch the shocking parts; and, mostly, most **electronic** control circuits doesn't use a voltage that could cause electrical shocks.

Comment: This picture should be marked _NSFW_.

Answer (score 1):

> Would wearing white latex gloves(doctor gloves) protects you from
>   getting shocked when repairing electronics?

No, per the other answer. And I would add that they might be dangerous to the equipment you are working on, depending on how static sensitive the components are, as static may build up on the outside of the glove.

> And is there a reason why you seldom see anyone wearing gloves when
>   dealing with electronics?

For one reason, gloves hinder your ability to work with small parts. While there are anti-static gloves available, more often engineers use anti-static wristbands. They’re cheap and effective.

[image]

Comment: You do not wear anti-static wristbands when the equipment is power on.

Comment: You do wear anti-static wristbands when equipment is on, if you care about ESD.

Comment: @TestDeviant It depends what worth more, the equipment or you.

Comment: And on what conductive parts are accessible and at what voltage.

Comment: This answer was just to point out the potential risk to the electronics, as an addendum to the OP.